# C++ lambda expressions - How does the compiler interpret them?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I just starter learning the new features in C++ 11. I was reading about lambdas in C++ Primer (Stanley Lippman) and was experimenting with them.

I tried the following pieces of code:

```
auto func() -> int (*) (){
    //int c=0;
    return []()-> int {return 0;};
}

int main(){
    auto p = func();
}
```

This code compiled fine. So I guess lambdas without any captures are just generated as normal functions by the compiler and we can use a normal function pointer to them.

Now I changed the code to use captures:

```
auto func() -> int (*) (){
    int c=0;
    return [=]()-> int {return c;};
}

int main(){
    auto p = func();
}
```

But this failed to compile. I got the following compilation error while using g++:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int (* func())()’:
main.cpp:6:31: error: cannot convert ‘func()::__lambda0’ to ‘int (*)()’ in return
return [=]()-> int {return c;};
```

From the error I can understand that it is not a normal function that is generated and it might probably be a class with an overloaded call-operator. Or is it something else?

My questions : How does the compiler handle lambdas internally? How should I pass around lambdas that use captures i.e. what should be the return value from func()? I cant currently think of a use case where I would need to use lambdas like this but I just want to understand more about them. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All lambdas are function objects with implementation defined type called *closure type* with a `operator()` member. Every lambda expression has it's own unique closure type, too.

Lambdas without a capture can be *converted* to a function pointer. Whether or not compiler generates a normal function behind the scenes is an internal detail and shouldn't matter to you.

It's not possible to return a lambda that's defined inside a function. There are few things that prevent this - you don't know the name of a type of lambda expression, you can't use a lambda expression inside a `decltype` and as already said, two lambda expressions (even if lexically identical) have different types.

What you can do is use `std::function`:

```
std::function<int()> func()
{
    int i = 0;
    return [=]()-> int {return i;};
}
```

This way works with captures, too.

Or something like this:

```
auto f = []{ return 0; };

auto func() -> decltype(f)
{
    return f;
}
```

EDIT: The upcoming C++1y standard (more specifically, return type deduction), however, will allow you to do this:

```
auto func()
{
    int i = 42;
    return [=]{ return i; };   
}
```

Comment: The only answer to mention the conversion to function pointer!?? +1 Note that you can return a lambda from a lambda, and in C++1y also from a function, via return type deduction. The type of a lambda expression is *never* a function type for any observable behaviour (of course, it is implemented typically as a (member) function). For example, it is guaranteed that a lambda won't match some generic `Ret(Params...)` in template type deduction.

Comment: @dyp Right, thanks. I updated with a return type deduction example.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is free to decide how to generate the type of a lambda function. It generates a function object that means you can invoke it by `()`. But the type can be different in various situations. Every single lambda can has a unique type. A simple lambda (doesn't capture anything) can be stored in a pointer to function.

In C++11, to wrap a lambda which captures data, you can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
auto func() -> std::function<int()> {
    int c = 0;
    return [=]()-> int {return c;};
}
```

In C++14, it has [function return type deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Function_return_type_deduction), let the compile handle it:

```
auto func() {
    int c = 0;
    return [=]()-> int {return c;};
}
```

Comment: Non-capturing lambdas cannot be stored in a pointer to function: they can be converted to a pointer to function.

Comment: @Yakk: Can you explain the difference between `be stored` and `be converted`? If you mean non-capturing lambdas will be cast before storing to pointer to functions then you're wrong. Lambdas have not specific types, who knows, maybe compiler uses pointer to function type for simple lambdas and they can straightly be assigned to pointer to functions.

Comment: A lambda will **not** match a pointer to function `template` function, guaranteed.  So no, I do not believe you are right.  In practice, every compiler uses a generated unique type which makes inlinimg of the call trivial: a function pointer makes inlinimg tricky and fragile.  So in theory, and in practice, it is a conversion to a different type with different properties.

Answer (score 2):

A function cannot return a lambda function itself. If you write:

```
auto func() -> int () {
    int c=0;
    return [=]()-> int {return c;};
}
```

Then GCC complains:

```
lambda.cpp:3:21: error: function return type cannot be function
 auto func() -> int (){
```

So the solution is to wrap the return object into a `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>
    auto func() -> std::function<int ()> {
    int c=0;
    return [=]()-> int {return c;};
}

int main(){
    auto p = func();
}
```