# What is the mechanism of C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, scope, reference, initialization

I am studying lambda.

But I have a question.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 10;

    auto l1 = [&](){
        x = 5;
        return x;
    };

    auto l2 = [&, x = x + 100](){
        return x;   
    };

    cout << l1() << endl;
    cout << "main  x  : " << x << endl;;
    cout << l2() << endl;
    cout << "main  x  : " << x << endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
5
main x : 5
110
main x : 5
```

Why is not this the output?

```
5
main x : 5
105
main x : 5
```

Because of inline, is the output going to be like that?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a question.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ lambda expressions - How does the compiler interpret them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894157/c-lambda-expressions-how-does-the-compiler-interpret-them)

Comment: You didn't ask any questions, but I guess you wonder why `l2()` prints 110 instead of `105`. Because when `l2` is constructed `x` is still 10. `x` is changed to `5` when `l1` is called - what happens after `l2` construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this declaration of lambda

```
auto l2 = [&, x = x + 100](){
    return x;   
};
```

You are introducing a new variable (data member) `x` in the scope of the lambda and initialize it by the expression `x + 100` where `x` is the local variable declared in main. So the original variable `x` will not be changed. The lambda returns the value of the new variable `x` of the lambda. The local variable `x` declared in main will not be changed.

The capture default `&` is redundant because neither variable is captured.

So the lambda can be rewritten like

```
auto l2 = [x = x + 100]{
    return x;   
};
```

It looks similarly as a ctor initialization. Consider for example

```
struct A
{
    const int x;
    A( int x ) : x( x ) {}
                 ^^^^^^
};
```

Here within the parentheses there is used the local variable (parameter) `x`. Outside the parentheses there is used the data member `x`.

Opposite to the lambda above this lambda

```
auto l1 = [&](){
    x = 5;
    return x;
};
```

captures the local variable `x` by reference. As result it is changed by the lambda.

As for the output

```
110
```

then the local variable `x` was used in the definition of the second lambda when it was not changed yet by the call of the first lambda.

When the second lambda was defined the local variable `x` was initialized like

```
int x = 10;
```

If you insert the second lambda definition after the call of the first lambda as for example

```
cout << l1() << endl;
cout << "main  x  : " << x << endl;;

auto l2 = [x = x + 100]{
    return x;   
};
```

then you will get the output

```
5
main  x  : 5
105
main  x  : 5
```

Comment: For what is the use of ``&`` here ?

Comment: @deoncagadoes It is a default capture for local variables by reference. You can remove it in your lambda because neither variable is captured.

Comment: sorry, The question has changed.
I want you to take a look at it again.

Comment: @HwanE I have answered your question.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow 
I did not know that the initialized variable was const. Thanks!!

Comment: Do note that the member is not const.  The `operartor()` is const.  You can remove that though my declaring the lambda mutable.

Comment: @NathanOliver The data member x in the second lambda is indeed a const data member, You may not write for example     auto l2 = [x = x + 100]{
        return x += 10;   
    };

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's because the `operator()` is `const`.  Using `auto l2 = [x = x + 100] mutable { return x += 10; };` it will compile just fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes it will compile but it does not mean that in the original lambda the data member x is not constant.

Comment: See the *ClosureType::Captures* section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).  It has *The type of each data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity* so they are not const.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. I will look.